# Есть ли возможность записывать результаты в консоли на одной строке , но начиная с определенного места , двигаясь к левому краю?

Tags: c++

Я хочу записывать результаты в консоли на одной строке с какого-либо места , но затем продвигаться результатами влево. Я думал ,что смогу использовать `setw`:

```
cout << setw(40) << "cppstudio.com";
cout << setw(3) << "sike";
cout << setw(3) << "great";
```

Но всё равно sike выводится на новой строчке. Как заставить sike выводится до(левее) cppstudio.com, при условии, что cppstudio.com выводится раньше.

То есть хочется,чтобы выводилось таким образом:

```
great sike cppstduio
```

Comment: Поиграйте с символами `\r` и `\b`.

Comment: *sike выводится на новой строчке.* - sike выводится на той же строчке. в общем случае двигаться в обратную сторону и печатать поверх ранее напечатанного не получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нагуглил один способ, и для него понадобится библиотека windows.h:

```
COORD Position = {11, 0}; //позиция x и y
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, Position);
cout << "cppstudio.com";
Position = {6, 0};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, Position);
cout << "sike";
Position = {0, 0};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, Position);
cout << "great";
```